# getting min max and avg viewcount for each tag

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My data set is like this

```
id  viewcount title  answercount tags first_tag
 1         78    **            2   **    python
 2         87    **            1   **    pandas
 3         87    **            1   **    pandas
 4         83    **            0   **     Excel
```

Now i want to get min, max and avg of viewcount for each tag python, pandas and dataframe.

I have made separate database where first_tag are python, pandas and dataframe but i don't know how to get min max and avg of viewcount for each tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `groupby` follow with `describe`

```
df.groupby('first_tag').viewcount.describe()
Out[89]: 
           count  mean  std   min   25%   50%   75%   max
first_tag                                                
Excel        1.0  83.0  NaN  83.0  83.0  83.0  83.0  83.0
pandas       2.0  87.0  0.0  87.0  87.0  87.0  87.0  87.0
python       1.0  78.0  NaN  78.0  78.0  78.0  78.0  78.0
```

Comment: @Wem-Ben thank you very much for help, but can you tell me how can i get output where i just want detail about python and pandas not any other value.

Comment: @BarotShalin `df.loc[df.first_tag.isin(['python','pandas'])].groupby('first_tag').viewcount.describe()
`

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for, thank you very much for help! Last question can you tell me how does groupby function exactly works?

Comment: @BarotShalin you can check with https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html